# How to select named columns from a DocumentTermMatrix in R using tm

Tags: r, tm

I have written the code to generate the document term matrix in R using the 'tm' package.

Now, I have to select the frequency values in the matrix only for a selected named columns. So I want to subset the matrix based on a list of terms. If any of the terms (like terms = c('medium', 'high', 'low')) are present as columns in the document term matrix, I want only those columns to appear in the output matrix.

What is the method and how is the code in R written for this?

I looked at the document term matrix and it contains values for i, j and v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
terms <- c('medium', 'high', 'low')
inspect(dtm[1:5, intersect(colnames(dtm), terms)])
# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 5, terms: 2)>>
#   Non-/sparse entries: 0/10
# Sparsity           : 100%
# Maximal term length: 4
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
# 
# Terms
# Docs  high low
# 127    0   0
# 144    0   0
# 191    0   0
# 194    0   0
# 211    0   0
```